# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Describe'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am very new to Python. Reading up on new material for class, I had to copy and paste a few examples to see how things work. So, I copied and pasted code from this website ( https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog485/node/54 ) under the topic 'Looping in GIS Models'.
Here's mine:

```
import arcpy

try:
    arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\dan and kathryn\Desktop\school\programming\Lesson1"

    fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()


    for featureClass in fcList:
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management (featureClass, "C:\Users\dan and kathryn\Desktop\school\programming\Lesson 2\PracticeData/" + featureClass)
except:
    print "Script failed to complete"
    print arcpy.GetMessages(2)
```

Here's the error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages\pythonWin\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 325, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "C:\Users\dan and kathryn\Desktop\loops_gis.py", line 1, in <module>
    import arcpy
  File "C:\Users\dan and kathryn\Desktop\arcpy.py", line 5, in <module>
    desc = arcpy.Describe(featureClass)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Describe'
```

Contacted my teacher and he wrote code and sent it to me but everything matches. All of the backslashes, indentations, everything except for folder locations. Not sure what is going on but he suspects this problem runs beyond what I've written in my code.

I've already had to alter the site-packages folder within pythonWin and it now contains:

```
# .pth file for the PyWin32 extensions
win32
win32\lib
Pythonwin
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\ArcToolbox\Scripts
```

Not sure what's going on or why 'Describe' is even popping up in the problems

Comment: Is `arcpy.py` that file's original name? There may be a naming collision there. Try renaming it to something else.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but bear in mind that your line `arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\dan and kathryn\Desktop\school\programming\Lesson1"` will not point to anywhere reasonable unless you escape your backslashes (use `\\` instead of `\`) or use a raw string (`r"C:\users\..."`)

Comment: I think @Kevin is right and this is a naming issue.  `C:/Users/dan and kathryn/Desktop/arcpy.py` is probably the `arcpy` that you're importing, not the module you intend.

Comment: @kevin, arcpy.py was actually a practice file I created not too long ago when the 'import arcpy' function wasnt working. i was running tests in there. i didn't even notice that in the error msg and just deleted it. after completely removing it from my computer  i am still receiving it within the error msg.

Comment: @adsmith, I changed my stings to raw strings, no luck. then tried escaping my backslashes to no avail.

Comment: @KMitzka Restart your Python Interpreter. If that doesn't work, restart your computer.

Comment: after `import arcpy`, add `print arcpy.__file__` and `print dir(arcpy)`.

Comment: After the second restart, everything worked :P Thank you, and I think it was the backslashes, sorry I am a newbie!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heres what i had the change (all in the backslashes, I had no idea):

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/dan and kathryn/Desktop/school/programming/Lesson1"

AND

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management (featureClass, "C:\Users\dan and kathryn\Desktop\school\programming\Lesson 2\PracticeData/" + featureClass)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever writing path string, use r"path with backslash". It will take care of the backslash and forward slash problem. Use 'os' module when, the paths needed to be joined.